# How to reduce number of SQL queries in Ruby on Rails 3 when fetching associated records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I have two tables *Projects* and *Tasks*.

In my Tasks index view I have a long HTML table with one column *belongs to Project*.

Now I noticed that Rails uses a separate SQL query to fetch the name of each Project.

Is there any way to streamline this? I think I've heard of some technique a while ago but can't quite remember what it was.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `includes` method on your initial Task query.

Example:

```rb
def index
  @tasks = Task.includes(:project).all
  ...
end
```

Comment: I feel I should mention that calling .all on the return of includes() is not necessary and actually could be considered an anti-pattern because it will eager-load the data instead of lazy-loading when the data is iterated on.